# How can I make KDE programs use the GTK+ theme specified with GNOME Tweak Tool?

Tags: gnome, kde, themes, gtk, numix

I have set the Numix theme as my GTK+ theme in Gnome Tweak Tool. This works for most programs, but the ones made with KDE don't care about it.

This is how every program should look:
[image: Tweak Tool follows the themes specified]
This is how KDE based programs look (I tested Kmplot and Step.):
[image: Kmplot]

I don't know if this is the expected behavior from KDE programs or not, but Kmplot did use the Numix GTK theme before I switched to Ubuntu GNOME from Plain Ubuntu (both 16.04LTS and I used Gnome Shell with Plain Ubuntu too).

How can I make KDE programs use the specified GTK+ theme?